# extern array goes undefined reference error, but works well for int

Tags: c++, extern

compile error : 
[build] main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `pallete'

example code:
common.cpp

```
const unsigned char pallete[] = {0, 60, 100, 119};
int a = 1;
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

extern const unsigned char pallete[];
extern int a;

int main() {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << pallete[0] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try building common.cpp

Comment: To be honest I'm kind of surprised it compiles, because the type of `pallete` is incomplete without specifying a size.

Comment: As for the linker error you get, how do you build your application? Are you building together with `common.cpp`, or linking with the object file created from `common.cpp`?

Comment: anyway avoid declaring extern global variables and global variables in general. pass them by parameter instead.

Comment: On a totally unrelated note, please don't use `char` for small integers, just use plain `int` (or in your case `unsigned` instead of `unsigned char`). Once you get the program to build you will notice that it doesn't seem to output anything for `pallete[0]`, because the `operator<<` function will treat it as a *character* and not an intege. If you want to print the integer value you need to cast it (e.g. `static_cast<unsigned>(pallete[0])`). If you're required to use `unsigned char` then please use `uint8_t` instead (to make it semantically clearer that it's not character data).

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare pallete `extern` in `common.cpp`. Right now `main.cpp` knows that it should "look for" pallete in separate file but `common.cpp` treats it as local due to being `const` as it says here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv#Notes

> Notes
>
> The const qualifier used on a declaration of a non-local non-volatile non-template (since C++14)non-inline (since C++17) variable that is not declared extern gives it internal linkage. This is different from C where const file scope variables have external linkage.

```cpp
extern const unsigned char pallete[] = {0, 60, 100, 119};
int a = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your compiler does what mine is warning about:
`Warnung: variable 'pallete' is not needed and will not be emitted`

If you add your `extern` statement also in the `common.cpp` it should work.

If you declare something `extern` you should always do it in some header which is included by everyone who wants to use the variable.

Answer (score -1):

extern can be added:

> **extern** const unsigned char pallete[] = {0, 60, 100, 119};

than translation unit treats it as external despite being const...

Comment: What does this answer add that is not already in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60865210/298225)?